# ConnectionError when trying to establish a connection with HarperDB

Tags: python

I'm encountering a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError when attempting to establish a connection with HarperDB. Here's the specific error message:

raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloud1-thellmike.harperdbcloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002850ECC8810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X33A.png)

I have already tried a few troubleshooting steps, but none of them have resolved the issue. Here's what I've attempted so far:

1. Added my network address to the HarperDB configuration, similar to how it is done with MongoDB Atlas. However, I couldn't find any feature or documentation specifically addressing this for HarperDB.
2. Verified that there are no errors in my code by carefully reviewing it. The code appears to be correct, and I'm confident that the issue lies elsewhere.
3. Attempted to diagnose any potential network problems by disconnecting and reconnecting my Wi-Fi. I also tried pinging the HarperDB URL (HARPERDB_URL = 'https://cloud1-mike.harperdbcloud.com'), but it failed. On the other hand, when I ping 8.8.8.8, it works fine.

I'm uncertain about the next steps to take in order to resolve this issue. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the ConnectionError i encounter when trying to connect to HarperDB gets automatically resolved when you switch to a different Wi-Fi network. This suggests that the problem is likely related to your network configuration or connectivity.